# not authorized being shown for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a before filter and def check priv to the users controller. It is suppose to be setup so that only admin can view/edit all profiles, and that only the created User can view their own profile. As before anyone could view/edit profiles. I have tried a few methods, none work. When I go to view profile as admin or even regular user I get the "not authorized" message.

Any help would be appreciated.

users_controller:

```
  before_filter :check_privileges, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def check_privileges
    unless current_user.admin? || current_user.id == params[:id]
       flash[:warning] = 'not authorized!'
       redirect_to root_path 
    end
  end
```

index.html:

```
   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if (current_user.admin? || current_user) == @user %>
        <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                      data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that method previously, and just C&P yours. Same problem. I have been brainstorming but anything I think of doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar method in my app, try something like this:

```
def check_privileges
 return if current_user.admin? # this user is an admin, if is not the case do:
 flash[:warning] = 'not authorized!'
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

**UPDATE 1**

Again, try to change the if condition as the follow

```
if (condition || condition)
```

or

```
if ((condition) || (condition))
```

The problem is that Ruby parsers stop at the first condition if not explicited declared.

**UPDATE 2**

I think that there are an error in the parentheses on your index.html.erb, try the following:

```
 <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if (current_user.admin? || (current_user == @user)) %>
        <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                      data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: @pwz2000 if you are a regular user the flash will show (in my example), if you are admin not (I have tested on my app)

Comment: It shows if I am an admin. Even though it is showing for user, it doesn't save the information. Redirects me to root and says I am not authorized. Previously if I updated profile it would remain on profile page. It's only setup to redirect to root url if your not authorized. So right now I'm not authorize no matter what role I have and it's not saving (due to not being authorized). I added index.html so you can see how the if condition looks with your method.

Comment: same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @pwz2000 I can't help you anymore not knowing more about your app. An advice that I can you give are the following: 1. check if in the db the value of "admin" is set to true for the admin 2. check accurately your code for some "bug" (for example in the index you call a user var and then an "@user" var) 3. check if other methods (such CanCan or similar) interference with your controller 4. do some debug for the variable you use or using some terminal "puts" 5. good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Food for thought maybe you could do something like this:

```
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.role? :administrator
      #Allow admin to access everyone account
    else
      access_denied unless current_user?(@user)
    end
  end
```

Then inside your view your view do the `if statement`. Or alternatively my best suggestion is to go with something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Something like this will allow you to set up role authentication really easily. If you have a look at it you can set a certain amount of rule in your `ability.rb` which you can then enforce on the view.

If you WERE to go with the method of CanCan you could do something like this in your ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
   # raise user.role?(:administrator).inspect
    if user.role? :administrator

      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User

    elsif user.role? :employee
      can :read, :all

    end
```

The above is an example.... So that in your `views` you can enforce this type of rule by doing something like

```
 <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if can? :manage, @user %>
        <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                      data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
```

Something like this should work. Your options are there hope this helps :)